# '\n' and 'None' appearing at end of console outputted List. How to remove them?

Tags: python, list, function, file

I'm new to files in Python and I'm having trouble removing the '\n' and the word *None* in my output console. Here's my code:

```
def function(inputFile, wordFile):
    input = open(inputFile, 'r')
    words = open(wordFile, 'r')

    wordList = []

    for line in words:
        wordList.append(line.split(','))

    print(wordList)
    words.close()

##call function
result = function("file1.txt","file2.txt")
print(result)
print()
```

my file2.txt/wordFile/words looks like this:

> hello,world
>
> 123,456

**This is the output I get:**

> ['hello', 'world\n']
>
> ['123', '456\n']
>
> None

I know there's a lot going on but how do I remove the '\n' and *None*?

Comment: `function` should _return_ the `wordList`, not print it. Regarding the `\n` there is e.g. `str.strip`

Comment: return did remove the 'None' part, thank you! But doesn't str.strip not work on Lists?

Comment: You must apply it to the string before it is splitted.

Comment: A good way to write your code would be: `with open(wordFile) as words: return [line.rstrip().split(',') for line in words]`. Thus, the whole function will be a one-liner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get rid of whitespace characters you can use `strip`:

```
wordList.append(line.strip().split(','))
```

Also your function does not not return anything, so `result = function("file1.txt","file2.txt")` will assign *nothing* to `result` also called `None` in python. To have it return something, use `return` at the end of the function:

```
return wordlist
```

It is also possible to return mulitple variables:

```
return var1, var2, ...
```

You can get them by

```
a, b, ... = function(..)
```

Comment: Just needed something else answered. The problem I just realized with this solution is that once I 'return wordlist', I can't return anything else for the remainder of the 'function'. Is there any way we can make this work without using return or by using two functions?